# sshd: disconnecting dead client using reverse port forwarding

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshd

On a sshd server, I want to disconnect all clients that are not connected any more and were using the reverse port forwarding.

I have added:

```
ClientAliveInterval 30
ClientAliveCountMax 2
```

in my sshd_config file but it doesn't seem to be used for clients that are only using port forwarding (the client doesn't have a shell on the server). The client is connected via:

```
ssh -N -R :port:localhost:80 user@server
```

Is there a specific setting to terminate the sshd session of the client when there has been no traffic on the reverse port forwarding for a specific amount of time?

Comment: could you add more information on the setup? When you say _port forwarding_, do you mean the one done by ssh or one setup by, say, iptables.

Comment: It's just a ssh question (not iptable involved). I have edited the question.

Comment: `not connected any more` and `when there has been no traffic on the reverse port forwarding` are different things. `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax` should be able to terminate a connection when the client is silently gone ([read more](https://superuser.com/a/1283733/432690)). When the client responds on demand, the connection is considered OK, even if there is no traffic via the tunnel, even if there has been no traffic for ten days. One may set a tunnel up and wait for a third party to connect, not knowing when it will happen. Lack of traffic via the tunnel means nothing.